# The user must supply a JDBC connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have a `DispactherServlet.xml` file which has the hibernate file configuration as

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/dibya/hbm/resource/model.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.username">root</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.password"></prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id = "hibernateTemplate" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name = "persister">
        <ref bean = "sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my controller, I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "Hello.htm")
public String HelloWorld(Model model) {
    boolean is = persister.isAllowCreate();

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("dibya");
    persister.saveOrUpdate(person);

    System.out.println("This is called"+is);
    return "HelloWorld";
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
```

Please tell me what am I forgetting to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hibernate config file is using wrong parameter names. Correct param names are as below:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class
hibernate.connection.url
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
hibernate.dialect
hibernate.show_sql
```

Correct your param names and try again.

EDIT: Refer this link for detailed list of param names: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can configure like this :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:/local/hsqldb</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">sa</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password"></prop>


                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${gloss.database.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/core/domain/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```